# Spring WS exception during security header generation

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws, wss4j

I am struggling with an old project which was upgraded to `Spring 5.3.23` , `Spring WS 3.1.6` and `WSS4J 2.4.1` . It is running in `WildFly 26.1.2` with `SAAJ 1.5.3` builtin

The project contains some REST Spring Controllers and one SOAP server endpoint with Wss4jSecurityInterceptor. After upgrade the SOAP endpoint returns error

```
WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.
```

When I remove the security interceptor it returns the response without issue. Due to separate logging issues I cannot get to the stacktrace. Does anybody have any clue? I tried various versions mixed but it is always the same. Thanks